# How many binary strings of length 8 are there that contain two or fewer 1s?

Tags: combinatorics

I need help understanding this.

So the way I did it was:

all 0's : $\binom{8}0 = 1$

one 1 : $\binom{8}1 = 8$

two 1's :  $\binom{8}2 = 28$

then, $28+8+1 = 37$

Therefore, there are 37 binary strings.

---

The part that I have trouble understanding is why does it work. Like for example, $\binom{8}1$. From my understanding, this means that there are 8 bits and I am choosing one $1$. Is this right? I'm so confused, I don't understand what this means.

Can someone help to explain this to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's confusing? There are $8$ strings containing a single $1$ because there are exactly $8$ places to put that one.  The $8$ strings are $1000000,01000000,00100000,00010000,00001000,00000100,00000010,00000001$.

Comment: Note:  I don't think it's good to write, e.g., "There are $37$ binary strings."  That's not what you mean.  What you mean is "There are exactly $37$ binary strings of length $8$ which contain at most two $1's$."  or you could say "There are exactly $37$ binary strings of the type we want" or something like that.

Comment: @lulu I got it thank you. I was thinking it the wrong way. So its basically there are 8 different ways to choose for a single $1$. Its just that binary stuff got me a little confused there.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck!